# Pandas Merge two databases with not matching time series

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, csv

Trying to merge 2 DB in Python, with one time range, but different time values.
С = pd.merge_asof(A, B, on='time')
gives
TypeError: No matching signature found

## A

| time | counter0 | counter1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:00 | 0.0172 | 0.0207 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:15 | 0.0483 | 0.0517 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:30 | 0.0621 | 0.0655 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:45 | 0.0897 | 0.0931 |
| 2021-05-27 19:10:15 | 0.155 | 0.155 |

## B

| time | rate | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:13 |  | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:13 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:14 | 0.42 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:14 | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:15 | 0.4 |  | 5 |
| 2021-05-27 19:10:05 | 0.1 | 2 | 3 |

I want C look like:

## C

| time | counter0 | counter1 | rate | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:00 | 0.0172 | 0.0207 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:13 | N/A | N/A | N/A | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:13 | N/A | N/A | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:14 | N/A | N/A | 0.42 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:14 | N/A | N/A | 0 | 3 | 4 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:15 | 0.0483 | 0.0517 | 0.4 | N/A | 5 |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:30 | 0.0621 | 0.0655 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2021-05-27 19:09:45 | 0.0897 | 0.0931 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 2021-05-27 19:10:05 | N/A | N/A | 0.1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021-05-27 19:10:15 | 0.155 | 0.155 | N/A | N/A | N/A |

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for an outer join?

```
c = a.merge(b, on='time', how='outer').sort_values('time')

                 time  counter0  counter1  rate    C    D
0 2021-05-27 19:09:00    0.0172    0.0207   NaN  NaN  NaN
5 2021-05-27 19:09:13       NaN       NaN   NaN  1.0  1.0
6 2021-05-27 19:09:13       NaN       NaN  0.00  2.0  2.0
7 2021-05-27 19:09:14       NaN       NaN  0.42  2.0  3.0
8 2021-05-27 19:09:14       NaN       NaN  0.00  3.0  4.0
1 2021-05-27 19:09:15    0.0483    0.0517  0.40  NaN  5.0
2 2021-05-27 19:09:30    0.0621    0.0655   NaN  NaN  NaN
3 2021-05-27 19:09:45    0.0897    0.0931   NaN  NaN  NaN
9 2021-05-27 19:10:05       NaN       NaN  0.10  2.0  3.0
4 2021-05-27 19:10:15    0.1550    0.1550   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Oh, that easy, thank you, sir, very much, you saved my day!